# Network Manager automatically turns off

Tags: 14.04, network-manager

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. My `network-manager` automatically turns off every now. Then, I have to restart it manually using the terminal.

How should I debug this problem?

Here is the `dmesg` output:

```
[27851.368090] wlan0: deauthenticated from f8:XX:XX:XX:XX:b5 (Reason: 6)
[27851.423459] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[27851.427772] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[27851.427777] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[27851.427780] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[27851.427783] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[27851.427785] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[27851.427787] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[27851.427789] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[27851.428215] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
[27851.432231] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: US
[27851.432236] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[27851.432239] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2700 mBm)
[27851.432241] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 1700 mBm)
[27851.432243] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[27851.432245] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5600000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[27851.432247] cfg80211:   (5650000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[27851.432249] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 3000 mBm)
[27851.432251] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[27867.139843] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

Comment: Can you clarify whether it is the `network-manager` *service* that is failing, or the on-screen `nm-applet`?

Comment: are you sure you have applied all the updates? this used to be a problem for me when 14.04 first came out but is no longer.

Comment: use the command `dmesg` to get info on what happens when the service fails or closes.

Comment: its the network manager which fails not the nm-applet

Comment: Could you check output of `grep NetworkManager /var/log/syslog` and `zcat /var/log/upstart/network-manager.log.1.gz`. May better to try, after it stops don't start service again, but switch to root `sudo su` and run `NetworkManager --no-daemon`. Then check its output before it turns off.

Comment: @RJadhav, does `NetworkManager --no-daemon` show errors?

Comment: Do you have this problem since you've installed 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

You can try disabling the `n` mode of the driver with these commands:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
```

If still has problems, try deactivating the power management of the card with this command:

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219014&p=12998326#post12998326

Comment: i tried, dint work!

Comment: What is the model/brand of your computer?

Comment: Its dell inspiron 15R

Comment: I edited my answer. Try now.